# Read only filesystem in ubuntu also I can't mount because read write is protected

Tags: mount, filesystem

Read only filesystem in ubuntu also I can't mount because read write is protected
Ubuntu 20.04
I tried `fsck`,`mount remount` etc.

My system is starting but I can't do anything because read write is protected.

If you need any log let me know

---

when system boot then after 1-2 minute this will happen

Comment: Unless a file-system was mounted RO, a common cause for a RW mounted file-system to *flip* to RO is because corruption was detected, or the disk itself is starting to fail. I'd explore disk health first (most old drives & modern SSD/NVME's use the same inbuilt SMART capabilities) - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: @guiverc my disk is fine. I can access it with operation on recovery mode

Comment: Sometime I face another issue `systemd-journard Can't Right entry Read only file system` I fix this issue using this command `sudo rm -rf /run/log/journal/*` and then ` sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald.ser-ice` and then reboot this solved errors. But how to solve this problem?

Comment: You aren't solving the issue; just removing the symptoms (*thus it occurs again*).  You should be reading the issues found in your systemd journal as to your actual problem that causes the RW to *flip* RO & investigate that.. The issue will re-occur until it's resolved; ignore it and it'll just re-occur & potentially get worse (*the main question is how quickly/slowly*). If parts of the disk are *bad*, other parts normally do work; only your drive's SMART will provide health details. For your actual issue you should explore your systems logs.

Comment: @guiverc finally my computer started successfully! but I don't no how it's working? I tried lot of commands?  How to avoid future problems I will never shut down my computer In any cost.

Comment: I am not sure but `badblocks -svnf /dev/sdXX` was solved my problem

Comment: `fsck` is a file-system check, it checks for logical errors, where as `badblocks` checks for bad sectors & with parameters can mark them as bad so the remaining disk can still be used; ie. `badblocks' checks for physical problems in the disk. SMART I mentioned in my first comment will give stats from the drive's own electronics; something you ideally do regularly so you can detect badblocks occuring which can be a sign of a failing disk... Yes you may have fixed the current issue; but I'd still suggest checking the health of a drive; otherwise you risk needing to repeat this in the future..